# Comput Spectrum of Idempotent

Tags: analysis, banach-algebras

Let **A** be a unital banach algebra and **a** in **A**
if **a** is *idmepotent* and **a** do not equal to 0 and 1

then

***the spectrum of* a** **= {0,1}**??

Comment: thankes mister Robert . put may you explane it more?

Answer (score 1):

Since $a = a^{2}$, by induction it can be shown that $a = a^{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then the spectral radius formula yields 
$$spr(a) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\| a^{n} \|^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \| a \|^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$$

Hence $\sigma(a) \subset B[0,1]$.

From the spectral mapping theorem for polynomials we get that $$\sigma(a) = \sigma(a^{n}) = (\sigma(a))^{n} ~~~~\forall~n  $$

Hence since  $\sigma(a) \subset B[0,1] \implies \sigma(a)= \{0,1\}$.

Comment: I don't get the last line.  $B[0,1] = B[0,1]^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, but the spectrum isn't $B[0,1]$.  You should use the spectral mapping theorem with the function $f(x) = x^2 - x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $a^2 - a = 0$ and the spectral mapping theorem strongly restrict the possible members of the spectrum of $a$.

Comment: What do you think of my answer?

Comment: If you have a chance please look at [my post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428347/proof-involving-invertible-elements-of-banach-algebra).